# Looping over two criteria in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
Spot_Datetime      State 
----------        ------
2016-01-02 08:00   CA
2016-01-02 08:03   AZ
```

I have another data frame that looks like this

```
Datetime           State    Sessions
----------        ------  ----------- 
2016-01-02 08:01   CA        1
2016-01-02 08:02   CA        4
2016-01-02 08:03   CA        3
2016-01-02 08:03   AZ        9
```

I currently have a loop that sums Sessions for a specific time window from the first dataset, but I would like it to match on State and Date. How can I do this in R?

Ideally, my dataframe will look like this (for example, a 10 minute window):

```
Spot_Datetime      State   Sessions
----------        ------   ---------
2016-01-02 08:00   CA         8
2016-01-02 08:03   AZ         9
```

I have a upper and lower window loop, can I use an If statement on the outer loop?

Data

```
d1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Spot_Datetime      State 
'2016-01-02 08:00'   CA
'2016-01-02 08:03'   AZ", colClasses = c('POSIXct','character'))

d2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Datetime           State    Sessions
'2016-01-02 08:01'   CA        1
'2016-01-02 08:02'   CA        4
'2016-01-02 08:03'   CA        3
'2016-01-02 08:03'   AZ        9", colClasses = c('POSIXct','character','integer'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to aggregate by interval groups by state and use whatever method you are comfortable with. Here is base

```
d1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Spot_Datetime      State 
                 '2016-01-02 08:00'   CA
                 '2016-01-02 08:03'   AZ", colClasses = c('POSIXct','character'))

d2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Datetime           State    Sessions
                 '2016-01-02 08:01'   CA        1
                 '2016-01-02 08:02'   CA        4
                 '2016-01-02 08:03'   CA        3
                 '2016-01-02 08:03'   AZ        9", colClasses = c('POSIXct','character','integer'))
```

So the idea here is to take the times (by state) in the second data set and use a window to create some intervals from the "key" data set which we will use as an additional grouping variable to get the sums.

For example, we can cut 0 to 60 minutes into 1-minute intervals and see which one the date-times from `d2` fall in (POSIXct counts by seconds, so we have to multiply by 60)

```
window <- 1
findInterval(d2$Datetime, d1$Spot_Datetime[1] + seq(0, 60, by = window) * 60)
# [1] 2 3 4 4

window <- 10
findInterval(d2$Datetime, d1$Spot_Datetime[1] + seq(0, 60, by = window) * 60)
# [1] 1 1 1 1
```

And now just do this by state. The only trick is matching which fields from `d1` will line up with `d2`

```
window <- 10
d3 <- merge(d2, d1, sort = FALSE)
d3$idx <- ave(1:nrow(d3), d3$State, FUN = function(x)
  findInterval(d3$Datetime[x], unique(d3$Spot_Datetime[x]) + seq(0, 60, window) * 60))

(d4 <- aggregate(Sessions ~ State + idx, d3, sum))

#   State idx Sessions
# 1    AZ   1        9
# 2    CA   1        8

merge(d1, d4[, c('State','Sessions')], sort = FALSE)

#   State       Spot_Datetime Sessions
# 1    CA 2016-01-02 08:00:00        8
# 2    AZ 2016-01-02 08:03:00        9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` package instead of loops.  First, define what the time windows are.  Second, cut the data into windows based on the Datetime column. (I've used a window of 10 minutes, so the data you provided only gets "cut" into a single window, but this should work for more data over a longer time period.) Finally, group the data by Datetime and state, and sum the sessions within each group.

```
# (Read in your d2 data)

# get 10-min cut points
start <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-02 08:00")  #Set beginning of first window in data
end <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-02 08:10")    #Set end of last window in data
winsize <- 60*10    # set window size in seconds
winbreaks <- seq(start, end, by=winsize)

# Cut the data based on the windows, 
# group it by window and State, 
# then sum Sessions within each group
results <- data %>% mutate(window=cut(Datetime, breaks=winbreaks)) %>%
                 group_by(window, State) %>%
                 summarise(tot.sessions=sum(Sessions))
```

If you've not used it before, `dplyr` syntax may take some getting used to.  But it's easy to get the hang of it once you start using it, and it will generally be a lot faster than loops, and probably be less prone to coding errors.

Note: I'm not sure what role your d1 table plays in this; it seems like you can do what you want just with d2, unless d2 has timestamps and states not present in d1 that you want to exclude from results.  If that's the case, also take a look at `dplyr` filter and join functions.

Comment: for a nice entry point into `dplyr` you can have a look to its [Introduction vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)